# ASP.Net C# request in retrieving values from input type textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

So our group is having a problem in retrieving the values input at the input type. here is the code that we use...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session.Remove("clicks");
        i = 0;
    }
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = 0;

    rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

    rowCount++;

    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

    Literal1.Text = Literal1.Text + "PRODUCT: <input type='textbox' runat='server' id='textboxu" + i + "' value='" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "' ></input> PRICE: <input type='textbox' runat='server' size='1' id='textboxe" + i + "' value='" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "' ></input>QUANTITY:<input type='textbox' runat='server' size='1' id='textboxq" + i + "'></input>TOTAL:<input type='textbox' runat='server' size='3' id='total" + i + "' ></input><br>";
        i++;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int check = 0; check <= i; check++)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(this.Request.Form["textboxe" + i + ".Value"]);
        double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(this.Request.Form["textboxq" + i + ".Value"]);
        double total = price * quantity;
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
        //this.Request.Form["total" + i] = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
}
```

we need to retrieve the answer also from the input type. i hope there are someone who will be willing to help us...

Comment: Your group clearly needs some basic background in asp.net, then get back to your other problem.

Comment: we have some background from our professor, but our professor is not that informative also about asp.net, she is still taking modules about asp.net so we haven't had a clue in any problems such as this

Comment: You are circumventing the entire asp.net infrastructure. Follow any basic example on creating a `runat="server"` `textbox`

Comment: This is no way to use webforms. If you want to learn more about it, check this out: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page And there are many more learning videos on that site.

Comment: You can not user runat="server" attribute in the string concatenation of html, remove runat="server" attribute and then try again.

Answer (score -1):

These are not server controls, so you should use name attribute instead of id.

```
<input type='textbox' name='textboxu" + i + "' value='" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "' ></input> 
...
double textboxu = Convert.ToDouble(this.Request.Form["textboxu" + i]);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is just slight change in syntax to get correct answer, see below snippet

```
 double price = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["textboxe" + i ]);
 double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["textboxq" + i]);
 double total = price * quantity;
 TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

//you need to use only request.Form rather than .value attribute
 string szValue =  Request.Form["txt1"]
```

hope it helps

Comment: After full page load, just right click webpage and click on view source and check what are the 'dynamic' id's of textboxes created by html and cross those id with your code id and check if same id is accessed by application